.Zip file cannot be opened by Rstudio
I am trying to use the stackByTable() function from the NEONutils-package to work with some open source data from NEON. This function is apparently supposed to unzip the files in my downloaded data and compile all of the csv files with files of the same type into one document for easier use in analysis.
When I run the code, however, I come up with this error message:
stackByTable("~/Downloads/filesToStack10072.zip")

Error in utils::unzip(zipfile = zippath, list = T) : 
  zip file 'C:/Users/j/Documents/Downloads/filesToStack10072.zip' cannot be opened

Does anyone know what's happening here?
Thanks
I tried downloading the files using the zipsByProduct function and manually. I also experimented with changing their names in my downloads. Removing the ".zip" from the file name in R results in the error:
Error in stackByTable("~/Downloads/filesToStack10072") : 
  Data files are not present in specified filepath.

So it appears it is successfully locating the files and just is unable to interact with them.

Can you open the zip manually in your operating system (i.e. not using R)?  Does it open correctly?

I can open them if I unzip them. Otherwise I get an error that says "Windows cannot complete the extraction. The destination path is too long. Rename the compressed (zipped) folder and try again". Perhaps that's part of the problem, but these files have a standardized naming system that I imagine is part of the code used for combining them, so I'm not sure if I can change the names.

I've had similar problems with very long file/folder names.  The length of the name is not just the file name but the entire path - if you can move the zip to a temporary location with a very short path (C:\temp\) it might work, but the path you have listed in your original question doesn't look excessively long.  What OS/file system are you using?

Oh shoot, I'm not sure- I'm on Windows 11 if that helps. That folder contains a bunch of additional folders with names like   NEON.D05.UNDE.DP1.10072.001.2023-07.basic.20240411T235922Z.PROVISIONAL   , and each of these folders contains multiple files with names like NEON.D05.UNDE.DP0.10072.001.categoricalCodes.20240411T235922Z.csv  , so perhaps name length is the issue here, but that code was written specifically for files arranged this way and with these types of names. Is it possible this is an issue with my computer not having enough memory or something like that?
